# Command phasescriptexecution failed with a nonzero exit development and production firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, run-script

I'm trying to add firebase for my own project in dev and production environtment.
I need to add GoogleService-Info.plist for Dev and Prod environment.

After add new run script phase. There's error show **phase script execution failed**.

```
GOOG_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Debug/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist
GOOG_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Release/GoogleService-Info.plist


GOOG_DST=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist


if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
  GOOG_SRC="${GOOG_PROD}"
else
  GOOG_SRC="${GOOG_DEV}"
fi

if [ ! -f "$GOOG_SRC" ]; then
  echo "Missing 'GoogleService-Info.plist' source at '${GOOG_SRC}"
  exit 1
fi

cp "${GOOG_SRC}" "${GOOG_DST}"
```

GoogleService plist located like image below
[googleservice plist location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Yb8.png)

**NOTE**

This will run smoothly if i'm using the same GoogleService-Info.plist **NAME** for both dev and prod

and i just tick the checkbox for 1 one of them in target Membership when i build the app. But it's really bother me to change it for every build environment changes